# Putting in RAM with a higher speed

Tags: macbook-pro, memory

I wondering if I put my 1600Mhz 8Gig (4gigx2) modules in a Macbook Pro 17" 620m (2010 model) if the speeds would be automatically reduced to 1066Mhz? I'm just asking because I don't want to damage the computer. I've read that this will happen, but I just want to ask around before hand :).

Answer (score 4):

The frequency rating on RAM is analogous to the top speed of a car, if it's max speed is (for example) 250 km/h, it can drive up to 250 km/h, but it won't break if u drive at 25 km/h.

Same for RAM. As long as it's the same DDR3 Standard, it will run, regardless of how high the max clock speed is.

Comment: So if the motherboard and CPU only support 1066Mhz, and the RAM is 1600Mhz. The memory will just decrease to 1066Mhz and run fine :). I really just don't want screw up the computer

Comment: meant to be question marks "?" :P

Comment: yes, I just thought you were referring to the Computer being faster and the ram being slower. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on manufacturer of your memory and how much specific stick is [compatible with your memory controller](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/38532/54644) and/or with [graphics chip](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/53340/can-i-use-1333-mhz-ram-in-a-1067-mhz-macbook-pro).

For example, my MacBook Pro mid 2010 13" (MacBookPro7,1) did not support Hynix 4GB PC3-12800 DDR3 1600 MHz sticks if used alone or 4GB+4GB, they work only if coupled (2GB+4GB) with pre-installed 2GB 1033 MHz sticks from Samsung.

Answer (score 0):

XAleXOwnZX already answered, but I'd like to confirm that this indeed works with you 2010 MacBook Pro. I've had a 13" 2010 MacBook Pro and upgraded using 1600 MHz RAM.